# using janrain api and adding modification to it

Tags: forms, authentication, janrain

I came across janrain while analysing a code base. I have read some about it. But my concepts are not so good in this regard. please excuse. It would be help full if I will find some easy hello world type of explanation to it.

Comment: What you want exactly Are you want Janrain Login or Janrain Social Login sample code ? Simple posting vague words. before that what you have tried ?

Comment: Your best place to start would be here:  https://docs.janrain.com/

Comment: yeah. I've been following that. thanks!